# Matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication

Hello (excuse my English), I have a big doubt in python with matrix multiplication, I create a list of lists and multiplied by a scaling matrix, this is what I've done and I can not alparecer perform a multiplication operation problem with indexes, I check with paper and pencil and it works, I'm doing something bad to accommodate indexes or am I wrong accommodating matrices from the beginning?

```
def main():
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    v = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    print "error python exe:"
    print "\tpython <programa.py> <num_vertices>"
A = []
for i in range(v):
    A.append([0]*2)
for i in range(v):
    for j in range(2):
        A[i][j] = input("v: ")  


print A 
    Escala(A)

def Escala(A):
    print "Escala"
    sx = input("Sx: ")
    sy = input("Sy: ")
    S = [(sx,0),(0,sy)]
    print S
    M = mult(S,A)
    print M



def mult(m1,m2):
M = zero(len(m1),len(m2[0])) 
    for i in range(len(m2)):   
        for j in range(len(m2[0])): 
            for k in range(len(m1)): 
                M[i][j] += m1[k][j]*m2[k][j]
    print M                 
    return M

def zero(m,n):
# Create zero matrix
new_matrix = [[0 for row in range(n)] for col in range(m)]
return new_matrix
```

Comment: Am fairly sure [DJV](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15003989/432913)'s answer is correct. You might want to check before doing the multiplication that the matrix dimensions allow multiplication though.

Comment: why aren't you using numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems wrong to me:

```
M[i][j] += m1[k][j]*m2[k][j]
```

shouldn't it be:

```
M[i][j] += m1[i][k]*m2[k][j]
```